# GNU libobjc gives segfault when sending message

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gcc

I'm trying to get a simple Objective-C program running on Ubuntu WITHOUT GNUStep, and this code works:

```
#import <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("hi");
    return 1;
}
```

But, when I compile the following code:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>

@interface MyObject : Object

-(void) printHello;

@end

@implementation MyObject

-(void) printHello{
    printf("Hello!");
}

@end

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MyObject* obj = [MyObject new];
    [obj printHello];

    return 1;
}
```

It compiles, with the following warnings:

```
main.m: In function ‘main’:
main.m:19:2: warning: ‘MyObject’ may not respond to ‘+new’ [enabled by default]
  MyObject* obj = [MyObject new];
  ^
main.m:19:2: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature [enabled by default]
main.m:19:2: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept [enabled by default]
main.m:19:2: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.) [enabled by default]
```

And if I then run a.out, it gives me a segmentation fault.

Is there a way to fix this WITHOUT GNUStep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fix because your broken code is calling unimplemented class method.
Please consult the runtime source and header, or just use GNUstep.

Comment: I tried it the same way on my Raspberry Pi, and it worked fine. Isn't there a way to get the same lobjc on my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: OK, I got it solved, using Clang, and explicitly linking to the weirdly placed libobjc-4.6 libraries

Comment: If it works then you are using legacy runtime implementation. Newer runtimes dont implement any kind of memory allocation. I'd say, stick with GNUstep for now, and try to get rid of it later once you understand how to manage object allocations manually.

Comment: Well, I found out that gobjc stopped working after version 4.7, but 4.6 works fine

Comment: Just to make it clear. I would not say 'working' because the behaviour was intended. The Object class's implementations were not there not because someone forgot something. Merry Xmas!